# JavaScript: How would I reverse ONLY the words in a string

Tags: javascript, string, function, reverse

How would i write a function that takes one argument that is a sentence and returns a new sentence where all words are reversed but kept in the same order as  the original sentence?

Test Case:

```
wordsReverser("This is fun, hopefully.");
```

Would return:

```
"sihT si nuf, yllufepoh."
```

This is what I have so far but notice that I cant get the period and comma to stay in place. I don't know if this was a typo by the interviewer or what?

```
function wordsReverser(str){
  return str.split(' ').
    map(function(item) {    
        return item.split('').reverse().join('');
    }).join(' ');
}

wordsReverser("This is fun, hopefully.");
//Output: 'sihT si ,nuf .yllufepoh'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
function wordsReverser(str){
  return str.replace(/[a-zA-Z]+/gm, function(item) {    
        return item.split('').reverse().join('');
    });
}

wordsReverser("This is fun, hopefully.");
//Output: 'sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.'
```

> **How It Works:** the `replace()` function will find each word and pass to the function which will reverse the word (the function returns the reverse word which replaces the word in the string) and all other should remain as that was before.

Comment: That totally did the trick man thanks! I can also understand how that works I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
function wordsReverser(str){
  return str.split(/(\s|,|\.)/).
    map(function(item) {    
        return item.split('').reverse().join('');
    }).join('');
}

wordsReverser("This is fun, hopefully.");
// Output: sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.
```

Regex to extract whitespace, commas and periods.

Comment: You can convert your RegEx with a character group: `([\s,.])`

Answer (score 1):

```
function wordsReverser(str){
  return str.split(' ').
    map(function(item) {    
        var letters = item.match(/[a-z]*/i);
    return item.replace(letters[0], letters[0].split('').reverse().join(''));
}).join(' ');
```

}

```
 wordsReverser("This is fun, hopefully.");
//Output: 'sihT si nuf, yllufepoh.'
```

Most likely not fool proof

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm would be something like this:

```
placeholder_array = [];
  result = '';
  foreach char in inputstring
    if(char !=',' || char != '.'){
         add char to placeholder_array;
    }
    else{
         result = result + reverse of placeholder_array
         placeholder_array = []
    }

   result = result + reverse of placeholder_array
```

If it's an interview question, I think they'd like more like an algorithm than exact syntax of the language.

Comment: So, this would only work with commas and periods right? For example what if the characters were an apostrophe and a question mark, thats where Regex comes in as [Tareq Mahmood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5645769/tareq-mahmood) demonstrated.

Comment: @FreddieCabrera, you can add more conditions, basically an exclusion list of chars

Comment: Ok I can see how you can do that as well, but wouldn't that be time consuming if you had many chars? I apologize if these are noob questions it's only because I am one haha.

Comment: @FreddieCabrera, yes, that's why I said it's likely that they want to see how you solve the problem logically rather than some neat trick with regex in an interview.

Comment: I see, I will study how your answer so that I can better understand it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, from what I see you are just reversing the string, the period and comma are associated with the string.  The way I am thinking about making it work is grabbing the Regex values, removing them with their index, then insert when youre done at the original index.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Not the best looking code or the fastest, but it works.

```
solve = (sentence) => sentence.split('').reverse().join('').split(' ').map(el => el.split('').join('')).reverse().join(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

For the Codewars challenge, I used a similar solution to the above, however included in my regex pattern a . and other special characters to ensure that there would be a total reverse in each string element.

```
function reverseWords(str){
    //Using replace, we can pass a regex object or literal pattern.
    //We pass this to a function as the second parameter
    //The functions return value will be used as the replacement string
    return str.replace(/[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-|a-zA-Z]+/gm, function(item) {    
          return item.split('').reverse().join('');
      });
}
```

Comment: Hi dwbra, thanks for taking the time to answer this question. One slight tweak to your answer that I would suggest is to specifically link to the answer you're referencing when you say "I used a similar solution to the above" so to make it explicit which solution you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function reverse(string) {
  let data = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g).join("");
  data = data.split("").reverse().join("");
  let index = 0;
  let result = "";
  for (let i of string.split("")) {
    if (i.match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
      result += data[index];
      index += 1;
    } else {
      result += i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(reverse("a-bcd-ef-ghi--jkl-m!!"));
```

reverse only alphabet in a string in which some special characters exist and also some digits exists but its reverse only alphabet characters

Answer (score 0):

```js
let string = "2i3u42idospo233!@kl!@#iio%%^hh^GFG&JK&";

function reverse(string) {
  let match = string.match(/[a-zA-Z]/gi).reverse();
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (!string[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]/)) {
      match.splice(i, 0, string[i]);
    }
  }
  return match.join("");
}

console.log(reverse(string));
```